# Running Chef recipes using Vagrant on Windows host: issue with SSH

Tags: windows, ssh, chef-infra, vagrant

I use Vagrant to create a CentOS VM on Windows host and connect to it, so far so good.

Next I want to use Chef to provision stacks on VM that was created. I tried with local directory cookbooks as well as providing urls to recipes, but that probably fails because it can't ssh to guest box, as seen from error:

`SSH authentication failed! This is typically caused by the public/private
keypair for the SSH user not being properly set on the guest VM. Please
verify that the guest VM is setup with the proper public key, and that
the private key path for Vagrant is setup properly as well.`

So my first question is:

1) How do I make sure SSH works within same window that brought up guest OS in Windows Host so that all scripts execute well?

Now when I comment below line in vagrantfile

```
config.ssh.username = "root"
```

Above error goes away, but I get another error:

`The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!`

mount -t vboxsf -o uid=`id -u vagrant`,gid=`id -g vagrant` v-csr-2 /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/chef-solo-2/roles

Which is because the user vagrant does not have enough access on box, which is my second question:

2) How do instruct Vagrant to run all commands with sudo or su access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I managed to get SSH working:

### install cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/)

setup openssh from within cygwin

### add ~/.ssh/id_rsa_vagrant

download from [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/master/keys/)

### modify ~/.ssh/config

Host localhost
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_vagrant

### modify rights on ssh directory

chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*

Everything should be working fine.

Comment: One once would be more than enough, good luck with chef, it's kind of hard to get into...

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to use batch file and same command prompt window from Windows to connect to VM.

So here are steps:

- You need to have putty installed on same machine.
- You will need to configure path to putty executable in following batch script
- Use the batch file to connect to your box

Here goes the batch file:

@echo off
REM
REM  This is a replacement for the "vagrant ssh" command on Windows
REM  (since "vagrant ssh" doesn't actually work on Windows).
REM 
REM  PuTTY must be installed. If it is not installed in
REM  "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY" then set the PUTTY_DIR environment
REM  to point to the installed location. 
REM
REM  As with any vagrant command this should be executed in the directory
REM  containing the Vagrantfile.
REM

setlocal enableextensions

if "%PUTTY_DIR%" == "" (
    REM Default location of PuTTY if the Windows installer is used.
    set "PUTTY_DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY"
)

if not exist "%PUTTY_DIR%" (
    echo ERROR: PuTTY not found. 
    echo Install PuTTY or check setting of PUTTY_DIR.
    goto end
)

for /F "tokens=1,2" %%A in ('vagrant ssh-config') do (
    if "%%A" == "HostName" (
    set VagrantHostName=%%B
    )
    if "%%A" == "Port" (
    set VagrantPort=%%B
    )
    if "%%A" == "User" (
    set VagrantUser=%%B
    )
    if "%%A" == "IdentityFile" (
    set IdentityFile=%%B
    )
)

if "%VagrantHostName%" == "" (
    goto end
)

if exist %IdentityFile%.ppk (
    set "VGPUTTY_OPTIONS=%VGPUTTY_OPTIONS% -i %IdentityFile%.ppk"
) else (
    echo.
    echo TIP: For password-free Vagrant VM login use PuTTYGen to generate
    echo      this file: %IdentityFile%.ppk 
    echo      from file: %IdentityFile%
    echo.
)

start "%VagrantHostName%:%VagrantPort%" "%PUTTY_DIR%\PuTTY.exe" %VGPUTTY_OPTIONS% %VagrantUser%@%VagrantHostName% %VagrantPort%

:end